# Inspect Android WebView with chrome dev-tools shows error 404

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

I want to debug/inspect my Cordova app via the Chrome DevTools. This always worked like a charm on all of my devices until about last week. Today I always get an empty window where it says:
`HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

When I open the console for the devtool-window I find the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this._pendingExtensionDescriptors.pushAll is not a function
    at DevToolsAPIImpl.addExtensions (devtools_compatibility.js:89)
    at <anonymous>:1:13
```

When i follow the link to the devtools_compatibilty.js I find the following function:

```
    /**
     * @param {!Array.<!ExtensionDescriptor>} extensions
     */
    addExtensions(extensions) {
      // Support for legacy front-ends (<M41).
      if (window['WebInspector'] && window['WebInspector']['addExtensions']) {
        window['WebInspector']['addExtensions'](extensions);
      } else {
        // The addExtensions command is sent as the onload event happens for
        // DevTools front-end. We should buffer this command until the frontend
        // is ready for it.
        if (this._addExtensionCallback) {
          extensions.forEach(this._addExtensionCallback);
        } else {
          this._pendingExtensionDescriptors.pushAll(extensions);  // <-- line 89
        }
      }
    }
```

I uninstalled all extenstions from Chrome - nothing happend.
I'm running Chrome for Mac Version 79.0.3945.130

Is anyone else facing this problem or can tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: They regularly break compatibility with older mobile clients. Use an older portable Chrome on desktop. If it works, you can report the bug on https://crbug.com.